# android камера сохранить запись в свой альбом

Tags: android, activity, android-intent, камера

благодаря вызову камеры устройства

```
 static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

private void dispatchTakeVideoIntent() {
    Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    }
}
```

я могу записывать видео.
Видео записывается в альбом камера, Но мне нужно, чтобы видео записывалось в мой альбом.
Например: я снял видео, и программа сама создает альбом допустим имя фамилия и там сохраняет мое видео.КАК ЭТО РЕАЛИЗОВАТЬ?ЗА РАНЕЕ БЛАГОДАРЮ ЗА ПОМОЩЬ

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
"/appsalbum/example.jpg";
File file = new File(path);
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
startActivityForResult( intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE );
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось, не создает альбом